# onEdit(e) DriveApp.getFileById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having issues getting the following to work.
The intent was on edit to push information from the specific cell or cells of active sheet to specific cells on a separate worksheet.
Note: I am new to google sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Working");
    var cell = source .getActiveCell();    
    if (cell.getRow() == 9 && cell.getColumn() == 2) {
        var target = DriveApp.getFileById("1biaIVlafaNQTHjtR8ctASCpDmC2O1wwfJfAUCmzIztI")
           .getSheetByName("Master_Sheet");
        target.getRange("A1").setValue(cell.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this question as it doesn' t **show** any research effort. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work is because you are using `onEdit()`. This is a simple trigger that will fire off whenever you edit the sheet. Since simple triggers cannot perform operations that require authorization you are limited to working **only in the Spreadsheet** and cannot access any other files.

Read up on restrictions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: I do not think that is the case. it may do more with the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to push information to the target sheet using the following code.

```
function myFunction() {
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("A3:C3").getValues();
  sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pyJzZ86WDh2FNXFufUAt2SkAUod32i7AzvG0EKmnvEU").getSheetByName("Destination");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData); 

};
```

Comment: Now that information can be pushed to another sheet, I need to address the original issue. sending information from "source" sheet range "A3:AA3" to the "Target" sheet  where the target row = "source" sheet "B2" and the target columns "AA:AB". I assume the column will be handled using Offset(). just not sure how to put it together.